# Boundary Value Problem and FullSimplify

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

I'm confused about the output Mathematica is giving me when solving a boundary value problem of the form:

```
eq = ϵ y''[t] + 2 y'[t] + 2 y[t] == 0;
bc1 = y[0] == 0;
bc2 = y[1] == 1;

aSol = y[t] /. DSolve[{eq, bc1, bc2}, y[t], t][[1]][[1]]
```

This yields the correct answer, and produces plots like this for `ep=1`, `ep=0.1`, and `ep=0.01`.

```
Plot[{
  aSol /. ϵ -> 1,
  aSol /. ϵ -> 0.1,
  aSol /. ϵ -> 0.01},
 {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", "y(t)"}]
```

[image]

So far, so good!

However, if I simply ask Mathematica to `FullSimplify[aSol]`, the resulting solution is no longer correct, and it does not satisfy one of the boundary conditions:

```
aSolSimpl = FullSimplify[aSol]

Plot[{
  aSol /. ϵ -> 0.05,
  aSolSimpl /. ϵ -> 0.05
  }, {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", "y(t)"}]
```

[image]

What's going wrong here?

Comment: i think because you assign Epsilon different values.
i used Full Simplify and it was fine with me 
use it as follow to check

aSol = y[t] /. DSolve[{eq, bc1, bc2}, y[t], t] /. \[Epsilon] -> 1

aSolSimpl = FullSimplify[aSol] /. \[Epsilon] -> 1



Plot[{aSol}, {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "y(t)"}]
Plot[{aSolSimpl}, {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "y(t)"}]

Comment: @dpholmes Plotting `Plot3D[Evaluate[{aSol, FullSimplify[aSol, \[Epsilon] > 0]}], {t, 0, 
  1}, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]` reveals that it might be a precision problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior seems due to precision problems, as Henrik suggested in comments:

```
aSol = DSolveValue[{eq, bc1, bc2}, y[t], t];
aSolSimpl = FullSimplify[aSol];

Plot[Evaluate[aSol /. ϵ -> {1, 1/10, 1/100}], {t, 0, 1}]

Plot[
 Evaluate[aSolSimpl /. ϵ -> {1, 1/10, 1/100}], {t, 0, 1},
 WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]